# Rotated rectangle with the bounding box having a specific aspect ratio

Tags: geometry, rotations

**Edit**:
You can calculate the bounding box for a rotated rectangle. If you change the rotation of the rectangle, the aspect ratio of the bounding box changes too.

I have a rectangle with a fixed aspect ratio. I need to find the angle that my rectangle must be rotated by, to make it's bounding box have a specific aspect ratio.

example:
I have an rectangle with an aspect ratio of 16:9. By how many degrees do I need to rotate it, to make it's bounding box have an aspect ratio of 4:3?

**Origial post**:

I've had this problem for the last few days, but wasn't able to come up with an solution.

I have:

- a box `box1` (blue) with fixed width `a` and height `b`
- a box `box2` (red) with a fixed aspect ratio, it can be scaled

I need:

- the angle by which `box2` must be rotated

My problem:
I want to put `box2` diagonally inside `box1`. `box2` should be as big as possible.

I'm having problems, finding the right angle for `box2`. My first idea was to calculate the angle of the diagonal of `box1`. I would then use this angle to rotate `box2`. As you can see, this only works if `box1` is a square:

[example 1 (working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVNry.png)
[example 2 (not working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHOBX.png)

As you can see in example 2, the red box doesn't have the right angle.

I would like to make `box2` as big as possible while keeping its aspect ratio. This means, that all four corners of `box2` will touch the sides of `box1`, which would also be forcing it to be 'diagonally centered' (? if that is propery english).

I was unable to find a solution for this problem. The best post I found was [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847282/fitting-rectangle-inside-another-rectangle-in-diagonal), but I don't know if and how I can deduce the solution to my problem from it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I suggest breaking the problem down into two sub-problems. First, given a fixed point on, say, the bottom edge of box 1, find the maximal box 2 that will fit. Once you have that, you can compute the area or side length of the inscribed box as a function of this point and solve a fairly standard optimization problem for it.

Comment: I think similar right triangles are the key to this problem.  The largest scaled version of  `box2` will touch `box1` on all four sides, with the degenerate case of both rectangles coinciding when aspect ratios allow.

Comment: In a similar vein, first solve the problem of finding the largest inscribed box for a fixed rotation angle, then optimize.

Comment: this is [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364531/maximum-area-of-rectangle-circumscribed-about-another-rectangle), but I assume that $a,b$ are fixed, so it's wrong to assume $a=b$, i.e. the bounding box is a square.

Comment: To get the result I want, I need to rotate my rectangle by a certain number of degrees, so that the bounding box of it has a specific aspect ratio. I think I didn't explain my problem well enough, so I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The inside box is skewed which makes it a more difficult geometry problem but the centers of the two are at the same point.

$(cd)^2 = (a-x)^2 + (b-y)^2$
and so

$d^2 = \frac{(a-x)^2 + (b-y)^2}{c^2}$………….(1)

$y^2 = d^2 – x^2$………………………….(2)

$d^2+ (cd)^2 = (a-2x)^2 + b^2$

$d^2(c^2+1) = (a-2x)^2 + b^2$

$d^2 = \frac{(a-2x)^2 + b^2}{(c^2+1)}$…………(3)

Substituting…..

$d^2 = \frac{(a-x)^2 + (b-\sqrt{(d^2-x^2)})^2}{c^2}$    gets rid of the y term

$\frac{(a-2x)^2 + b^2}{c^2+1} = \frac{(a-x)^2 + (b-\sqrt{(\frac{(a-2x)^2 + b^2}{(c^2+1)}–x^2}))^2}{c^2}$ gets rid of the d terms.

For $a = 9, b = 6$ and $c = 5$,

$117-18x-12\sqrt{\frac{4x^2-36x+117}{26}-x^2}-24\frac{4x^2-36x+117}{26} = 0$

then $x = .875, y = 1.625, d = 1.8456$ and $cd = 9.2280$

Edit: I corrected some errors and have verified the result.

To solve $117-18x-12\sqrt{\frac{4x^2-36x+117}{26}-x^2}-24\frac{4x^2-36x+117}{26} = 0$

Using Newton's method to solve for $x$...............

$x_1 = x_0 - \frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}$

Then $x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(n)}{f'(n)}$

$f(x) = 117-18x-12\sqrt{\frac{4x^2-36x+117}{26}-x^2}-24\frac{4x^2-36x+117}{26}$

and $f'(x) = -18 - \frac{(192x-864)}{26}-\frac{\frac{48x-216}{26}-12x}{\sqrt{\frac{4x^2-36x+117}{26}-x^2}}$

$x_0 = 1$

$x_1 = 1 - \frac{2.4617}{20.1016} = .8775$

$x_2 = .8775 - \frac{.0484}{19.3607} = .8750$

$x = .875$

Let me try to explain further but before I do, I did find an error in the derivative. The good news about this is it converges on a solution much faster. There are 3 equations with 3 unknowns $x, y$ and $d$. We are given $a, b$ and $c$ so we use the equation $\frac{(a-2x)^2 + b^2}{c^2+1} = \frac{(a-x)^2 + (b-\sqrt{(\frac{(a-2x)^2 + b^2}{(c^2+1)}–x^2}))^2}{c^2}$ to solve for $x$, then $y$ and $d$.

$a = 9, b = 6$, and $c = 5$ so......

$\frac{(9-2x)^2 + 6^2}{5^2+1} = \frac{(9-x)^2 + (6-\sqrt{(\frac{(9-2x)^2 + 6^2}{(5^2+1)}–x^2}))^2}{5^2}$

$\frac{4x^2 - 36x + 117}{26} = \frac{(x^2 - 18x + 81) + (6-\sqrt{(\frac{(4x^2 - 36x + 117)}{(26)}–x^2}))^2}{25}$

$25\frac{(4x^2 - 36x + 117)}{26} = (x^2 - 18x + 81) + (6-\sqrt{(\frac{(4x^2 - 36x + 117)}{(26)}–x^2}))^2$

$25\frac{(4x^2 - 36x + 117)}{26} = x^2 - 18x + 81 + 36-12\sqrt{(\frac{(4x^2 - 36x + 117)}{(26)}–x^2}) + \frac{4x^2-36x+117}{26} - x^2$

$25\frac{(4x^2 - 36x + 117)}{26} = - 18x + 117 - 12\sqrt{(\frac{(4x^2 - 36x + 117)}{(26)}–x^2}) + \frac{4x^2-36x+117}{26}$

$24\frac{(4x^2 - 36x + 117)}{26} = - 18x + 117 - 12\sqrt{(\frac{(4x^2 - 36x + 117)}{(26)}–x^2})$

$0 = - 18x + 117 - 12\sqrt{(\frac{(4x^2 - 36x + 117)}{(26)}–x^2})-24\frac{(4x^2 - 36x + 117)}{26}$

Hence $117-18x-12\sqrt{\frac{4x^2-36x+117}{26}-x^2}-24\frac{4x^2-36x+117}{26} = 0$

This just goes through my calculations to get to the Newton's method formula for this particular problem with actual values of $a, b$ and $c$.

Really, not knowing values for $a, b$ and $c$ beforehand, you should work with the equation

$\frac{(a-2x)^2 + b^2}{c^2+1} = \frac{(a-x)^2 + (b-\sqrt{(\frac{(a-2x)^2 + b^2}{(c^2+1)}–x^2}))^2}{c^2}$

$c^2((a-2x)^2 + b^2) = (c^2+1)((a-x)^2 + (b-\sqrt{(\frac{(a-2x)^2 + b^2}{(c^2+1)}–x^2}))^2$

Which will reduce to...............

$(a^2 + b^2) -2ax-2b\sqrt{\frac{(a-2x)^2 + b^2}{c^2 + 1}-x^2}-(c^2 - 1)\frac{(a-2x)^2 + b^2}{c^2 + 1} = 0$

Then for Newton's method.....

$$f(x) = (a^2 + b^2) -2ax-2b\sqrt{\frac{(a-2x)^2 + b^2}{c^2 + 1}-x^2}-(c^2 - 1)\frac{(a-2x)^2 + b^2}{c^2 + 1}$$

$$f'(x) = -2a + \frac{4(c^2-1)(a-2x)}{c^2+1}-\frac{\frac{-4b(a-2x)}{c^2+1}-2bx}{\sqrt{\frac{(a-2x)^2 + b^2}{c^2 + 1}-x^2}}$$

Where $a$ and $b \ (a > b)$ are the length and width of the outer rectangle and c is the aspect ratio $(\frac{\text{length}}{\text{width}})$ of the inner rectangle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This looks like the solution. The only thing I'm struggling with is solving $x$ or $y$. Could you please give me a hint on how to do this? Maybe I'm missing something obvious but when trying to solve one of them, my approach gets overly complicated.

Comment: x doesn't appear to be separable in the equation so It takes Newton's method to solve. $x_1 = x_0 - \frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}$ and then $x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$ etc, etc. I took a short cut and entered the equation into a graphing calculator and found the value of x at the x intercept where f(x) = 0.

Comment: I added the solution for solving x using Newton's method to my answer. I don't know whether this is out of the scope of your math topic but this problem is complex and requires knowing the derivative of the function to solve for x.

Comment: Sorry I took so long, I've finally found the time to get back to this problem. I'm still struggling to understand how you solved x y d cd. In the end I want to use this in a script. You should be able to pass a b c to a function. Each function should return one of the searched values ($x$/$y$/...). I understand your solution, however I'm unable to come up with a general formular for my script. I tried to convert your formular (the one before you inserted the values), so that I would be able to insert passed values and then solve via Newton's method, but I'm unable to find the solution.

Comment: @uniquestring I did some more work and have f(x) and f'(x) in terms of a, b and c. (see latest revision) I did add in how I determined this and checked out that these new equations work. I did find an error in the original derivative f'(x) which now makes it converge on a solution much sooner. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I'm happy to say that everything works fine. Maybe you could add a note, that $a$ must be bigger than $b$. At least when I tried examples with $a < b$ it didn't work. I solved that problem by rotating the outer rectangle by $90°$ and accounted for that when calculating the rotation of the inner rectangle. Thank you so much for your extensive and quick help.